# 'Plane' the numbers in any base!

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, base-conversion

*Inspired by [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4OvBB9KHMA).*

---

### What is planing?

In order to 'plane' a sequence of digits, you need to:

1. Identify the lengths of the 'runs' (adjacently repeated digits) in the sequence. Non-repeated digits count as runs of one.
2. Decrease the length of each run by one. Runs of length 1 become length 0.
3. Reconstruct the sequence, using the new lengths for the runs. Runs that are now length 0 are deleted altogether.

For example, planing the sequence \$1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6\$ would give us:

1. The length of the runs is demonstrated below:

```
 1  1  2  3  3  3  4  4  5  6
|____||_||_______||____||_||_|
  2    1     3      2    1  1
```

2. Decreasing the length of the runs gives us:

```
            1  1  2  3  3  3  4  4  5  6
           |____||_||_______||____||_||_|
              2   1     3      2    1  1
becomes:      1   0     2      1    0  0

(0s removed): 1  2  1
```

3. Using these lengths to reconstruct the original sequence, e.g. the first run is now length 1, the second length 0, etc., gets us our 'planed' sequence:

```
 1  3  3  4
|_||____||_|
 1   2    1
```

Note that the planing operation can also have a strength: the above example used a strength of \$1\$, but a strength of \$2\$ would decrease the length of each run by 2, strength \$3\$ by 3, etc.. In cases where this would make the length of a run go negative, the length just becomes 0.

E.g. with the above example and a strength of \$2\$, we get:

```
Input:       1  1  2  3  3  3  4  4  5  6
            |____||_||_______||____||_||_|
Run lengths:  2    1     3      2    1  1
Lengths - 2:  0   -1     1      0   -1 -1
Rounded to 0: 0    0     1      0    0  0

Output sequence:

 3
|_|
 1
```

### Challenge

Given a limit \$n\$, a strength \$s\$ and a base \$b\$, output the base-10 result of having 'planed' each of the numbers from 1 to \$n\$ in base \$b\$ with the strength \$s\$.

The basic steps to complete this are as follows:

1. Make a list \$x\$ of numbers 1 to \$n\$, including both 1 and \$n\$.
2. Convert each number \$x\$ in the list to base \$b\$.
3. Treating each digit of the base-\$b\$ number as an item of a sequence, plane the sequence with strength \$s\$.
4. Reading the sequence as a set of digits (or 0, in case of an empty sequence), convert the planed sequence back from base \$b\$ digits to a base 10 number.
5. Output this number and repeat for all values in \$x\$.

### Examples

Given \$b\$ = 4, \$n\$ = 250, and \$s\$ = 2:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,5,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,10,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

\$b\$ = 2, \$n\$ = 112, and \$s\$ = 3:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,3,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0]
```

\$b\$ = 12, \$n\$ = 1024, and \$s\$ = 1:

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,13,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,26,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,3,3,39,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,52,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,5,5,5,5,65,5,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,6,6,6,6,6,78,6,6,6,6,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.
- Standard loopholes apply.
- I/O may be taken/given in any acceptable, valid format. Each number in the sequence should be delimited in some way by a non-numeric digit, but the precise delimiting is up to you.
- You may assume \$b>1\$, \$n>1\$, and \$s>0\$. You may also assume reasonable upper bounds for these, depending on the capacity for number types in your language.
- If you wish, input arguments may have an offset (e.g. an input of \$1\$ to \$b\$ represents base 2), but this must be stated in your answer and should not impede the ability of your code to cover the whole range of allowed inputs.
- Output may be given as floats, ints, strings, etc., but all values must represent a numeric, base-10 value - so e.g. no `NaN`s in place of 0s.

#### Test code

For reference, here is the (shoddily-written and ungolfed) code I used to generate the above examples (in console JS):

```js
// called as f(length, base, strength)
const f = (l, b, s) => {
    return JSON.stringify(
        Array(l)
        .fill(0)
        .map((e, i) => i + 1)
        .map(e =>
            e.toString(b)
            .split('')
            .reduce((a, e, i, A) => (A[i - 1] && A[i - 1] === e) ?
                [...a.slice(0, -1), [a.slice(-1)[0][0], a.slice(-1)[0][1] + 1]] :
                [...a, [e, 1]], [])
            .map(e => [e[0], Math.max(0, e[1] - s)])
            .map(e => e[0].repeat(e[1]))
            .join('')
        )
        .map(e => parseInt(e, b) || 0),
        null,
        1
    )
}
```

Note that this implementation is not a complete/valid one, as it only works for \$b \le 36\$. As per the instructions, complete answers should be able to handle any base in theory, up to the integer limit of your language.

Comment: "Convert each number x in the list to base b." but what is x?

Comment: @Adám As in, 'for each number, calling the current number x, in the list, convert x to base b'.

Comment: @user True - I should probably note that. Yes, in theory, a 'real' answer should be able to handle bases >36, since the conversion is a purely internal process - no I/O has to happen in bases other than 10. So it's just my 'test' implementation that's flawed - not an indication of an added constraint.

Comment: When you say "_If you wish, input arguments may have an offset_", does that mean we can return the results for `[0,n-1]` instead of for `[1,n]`?

Comment: @Shaggy - unfortunately, no - you may, for instance, request to be given `n-1` instead of `n`, but the actual output must function equivalently. So since starting at 0 would mean that the core output of the program has changed, I wouldn't consider it a 'valid' interpretation of the rules. Tl;dr `[1, n-1]` is fine, `[0, n-1]` is not.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

*How* is Japt winning this (so far) despite the need for an essentially unnecessary byte in the `,`? It's making me feel like I've done something wrong!

```
õÈìV,ÈòÎcsW
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9cjsVizI8s5jc1c&input=MjUwCjQKMg)

```
õÈìV,ÈòÎcsW     :Implicit input of integers U=n, V=b & W=s
õ               :Range [0,U]
 È              :Map
  ìV            :  Convert to base V digit array
    ,           :  Does nothing (more accurately, prevents the V from becoming the first parameter of the next function)
     È          :  Pass through the following function and convert back to decimal
      ò         :    Partition between elements where
       Î        :      The sign of their difference is truthy (not zero)
        c       :    Flat map
         sW     :      Slice off the first W elements
```

Or, to avoid that pesky comma, we can reverse the second 2 inputs and do this, where `NÌ` is the last element of the array of all inputs:

```
õÈìNÌÈòÎcsV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=9cjsTszI8s5jc1Y&input=MjUwCjIKNA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
ɾvτƛ⁰nĠvȯf¹β
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BEv%CF%84%C6%9B%E2%81%B0n%C4%A0v%C8%AFf%C2%B9%CE%B2&inputs=250%0A4%0A2&header=&footer=)

```
ɾ            # 1...n
 vτ          # Foreach, base convert
   ƛ         # Foreach...
    ⁰        # Strength
     nĠ      # Each one grouped
       vȯ    # Trim each
         f   # Flatten
          ¹β # Convert back
```

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>32</s> 23 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Full program. Prompts for \$n\$ then \$s\$, then \$b\$.

```apl
∊⎕(⊣⊥∘∊⎕↓¨⊤⊂⍨1,2≠/⊤)¨⍳⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKNdoQBIdj3qm6rxqGvxo66ljzpmQPiP2iYfWvGoa8mjrqZHvSsMdYwedS7QB/I1gaK9m4EKQLr/K4BBAZeRqQGXEZcJl66uLhdMzNDQiMsYKIoiZmBkwmXIZWgEAA)

`⎕` prompt for \$n\$

`⍳` generate \$x\$, the **i**ndices 1 through \$n\$

`⎕(`…`)¨` establish the following tacit function, then apply it using each element of \$x\$ as right argument, and a prompted-for \$b\$-value as left argument:

`⊤` encode \$x_i\$ in base \$b\$

`2≠/` pairwise difference

`1,` prepend 1, giving a mask of starting positions of runs

`⊤⊂⍨` use that to partition \$x_i\$ re-encoded in base \$b\$

`⎕↓¨` prompt for \$s\$ and use that to drop the first that many elements from each run

`∘∊` enlist (flatten), then:

`⊣⊥` evaluate in base \$b\$

`∊` enlist (flatten)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
LIвεγIδ.$˜²β
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//0xJ0LLOtc6zSc60LiTLnMKyzrL//zI1MAo0CjI)

```python
L             # push range [1 .. n]
 Iв           # convert each number to base b (represented as lists of digits)
   ε          # for each list of digits:
    γ         #   group equal adjacent digits
     Iδ.$     #   remove s digits from each group
         ˜    #   flatten into a single list of digits
          ²β  #   convert back from base b
```

Comment: Lol, you beat me to it. I had just finished this exact program and was about to write an answer. :) Obvious +1 from me.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>107</s> 104 bytes

```r
function(x,b,s)Map(function(n,l=0:n,r=rle(n%/%b^l%%b))sum(rep(r$v,t<-pmax(r$l-s,0))*b^(1:sum(t)-1)),1:x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1NCsIwEEb3nsPAjEwxiboJ9gheodKUCIV0TPMjuX2sG0Fw9/jeBy@24Ed29@TW4nhyfXsUnvL8ZKhkKeFtDPCdmHwvDVPso3fA4ijs4IWwiKksEF2AuH9RvnZhGevGvkskEQ92AGU@l4ydQiRlKrbCfk4ZfvugL5LOpBF3/71SmjSdNt/e)

Goes out-of-range for the last test-case: add [+7 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY5NCsIwEIX3nsPAjEwxiXVT7BG8QqUpUQpxGvMjvX2MG0HQ3eN9H7wXincj20u0j2x5sn25Zp7SvDCsZCjiefTwqZhcLzu33GoySKEPzgKLvTCDE8IgxnyHYD2E7ZPSqfH3ca3ZNZEk4s4MoLq3krBRiKS6FUtmN8cE3zdAHyW1pBE3v7lSmjQd/nOpW6pOnSkv) to extend the range of amenable calculations and fix this.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
Ḋ¡€F
b€ŒgÇ€ḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjq5DCx81rXHjSgKSRyelH24H0g93tP7//9/I1OC/yX8jAA)

### How it works

```
Ḋ¡€F - Helper link. Takes a list of grouped digits D
  €  - Over each group:
 ¡   -   Do the following S times:
Ḋ    -     Dequeue; remove the first element
   F - Flatten

b€ŒgÇ€ḅ - Main link. Takes n on the left and b on the right
b€      - Convert each integer 1 to n to base b
  Œg    - Over each, group adjacent equal digits
    Ç€  - Run the helper link over each list of groups
      ḅ - Convert each back from base b
```

Comment: Ah right, quicks take the last argument which lets you tacitly get the 5th parameter without actually using `⁵`. Clever :P

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Kind of annoyingly, it's actually the same length as the [one liner](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/pUdOao5PSH@7oetS49dBCIM9NBUg83NH6//9/I1OD/yb/jQA), but I think this one is more elegant :)

Comment: Oh, you need the `⁵` to one-line it? That would explain why my attempt at golfing wasn't working. Unfortunate :/ but yeah I think this looks much nicer :P

Comment: @hyper-neutrino Yeah, `¡` only takes the last input if either 1) it  only gets one link (`Ḋ¡`), or if the second link is a nilad. Otherwise, it'd be read as `ŒgḊ¡`, not `Ḋ⁵¡`

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 92 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

Expects `(b)(s)(n)`.

```javascript
b=>s=>F=n=>n?[...F(n-1),(t=0,p=g=x=>x?g(x/b|0,x%=b,x==p?k++:k=1,p=x,k>s?t=t*b+x:0):t)(n)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcq7DoIwFADQ3a9gMdxrS20RF5JbNn4CGQCF8EhLpDEd/HfsbExMznim5tVs3XNcXWLs/bH3tLekN9IlGdKmqIQQJZhEIQdHkq80kCftiwH8uX1L7o/Uck@0FjNj@UwqFM9nvRWO3KllPpeYOwSDdV7Ve2fNZpeHWOwAPUQZQooQpVeJYrKjgZjHGLEovpkYD185zEvISqX/czigAplmP/L@AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
b => s =>               // outer functions taking b and s
F = n =>                // F = inner recursive function taking n
n ?                     // if n is not equal to 0:
  [ ...F(n - 1),        //   do a recursive call to F with n - 1
    (                   //   and append the next value to the array:
      t = 0,            //     t = final value converted back from base b
      p =               //     p = previous term in the sequence
      g = x =>          //     g is a recursive function taking x
        x ?             //       if x is not equal to 0:
          g(            //         do a recursive call to g ...
            x / b | 0,  //           ... using floor(x / b)
            x %= b,     //           reduce x modulo b
            x == p ?    //           if it's equal to the previous term:
              k++       //             increment k
            :           //           else:
              k = 1,    //             reset k to 1
            p = x,      //           update the previous term p to x
            k > s ?     //           if k is greater than the strength:
              t = t * b //             update t to t * b + x
                  + x   //             (i.e. add the digit x in base b)
            :           //           else:
              0         //             do nothing
          )             //         end of recursive call
        :               //       else (x = 0):
          t             //         return t
    )(n)                //     initial call to g with x = n
  ]                     //   end of array
:                       // else (n = 0):
  []                    //   stop the main recursion
```

Comment: @Shaggy Err ... right! :p Thank you.

Comment: Let's pretend that never happened! 

Comment: [A byte off for you](https://tio.run/##hcq7DoIwFADQ3a9gMdwrpbaIC8ktGz@BmAAC4ZGWSGM6@O/Y2ZiYnPFM9ave2ue42libR7f3tDekNlIFaVI6LznnBehYIgNLgq00kCPl8gHcuXkL5o7UMHdf85lkNkeRH47Nasst2VMTuUxgZhE0VllZ7a3Rm1k6vpgBeghShAQhSK4C@WRGDSELMYiC8KZDPHxlPy8@S5n8z/6A9ESS/sj7Bw)

Comment: @Ausername I didn't do that because I'm not 100% sure it's safe if the sequence starts with a zero.

Comment: @Arnauld Oh, true. It seems to work, but hard to tell.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 28 bytes

```
{(y/*'(1=#'?:')#z':y\)'1+!x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6rWqNTXUtcwtFVWt7dS11SuUreqjNFUN9RWrKjl4kqLNjI1sDaxNo5VqFMwIBIaEq3SiGiVxiTYbgrExLmBFvYT638jIDQk3gnUdwBRAQBKAoaGRtZG1iaEkgB+Ww0J+gC3fkOwbnOKfE2U/QAiAn+I)

Takes three arguments: `n => x`, `b => y`, and `s => z`. `s` needs to be offset by +1 (i.e. to apply a strength of `2`, pass in `3`).

- `(...)'1+!x` call the code in parenthesis on each value from `1..n`
- `y\` convert each value to base `b`, returning a list of digits
- `z':` take `s`-length rolling windows of the converted digits
- `(1=#'?:')#` filter out rolling windows containing more than one distinct digit
- `*'` take the first digit of each remaining rolling window
- `y/` convert back to original base

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
b€Œr_⁵Ż¤Œṙḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//YuKCrMWScl/igbXFu8KkxZLhuZnhuIX///8yNTD/NP9bMl0)

Takes three arguments in the form `n b [s]`.

*-1 byte thanks to @cairdcoinheringaahing*

### Explanation

```
b€Œr_⁵Ż¤Œṙḅ   Main dyadic link
b€            Convert each to base b (implicitly casting n to [1..n])
  Œr          Run-length encode
    _         Subtract [vectorized]
       ¤        (
     ⁵            The third argument
      Ż           Prepend a 0
       ¤        )
        Œṙ    Run-length decode
          ḅ   Convert from base b
```

Comment: I'm helping you outgolf me, but if you take `s` as `[s]`, you can save [1 byte](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9qZWxsef//YuKCrMWScl/igbXFu8KkxZLhuZnhuIX///8yNTD/NP9bMl0)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Is that an allowed input method? Great! I take it that we have a common goal to outgolf/match other golfing languages ;)

Comment: I'd just go for `b€Œr_⁵Œṙ+⁵ḅ` which needs no weird wrapping of inputs. (`-n` is treated as a run length of `0`.) - [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/pUdOao5OK4h81bj066eHOmdpAxsMdrf///zcyNfhv8t8IAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 155 bytes

```scala
b=>s=>1.to(_)map{y=>(0+:Seq.unfold(y){q=>Option.when(q>0)(q%b,q/b)}:\(0,0,0)){case(d,(c,p,a))=>if(d==p)(c+1,d,a)else(1,d,(a/:Seq.fill(c-s)(p))(_*b+_))}._3}
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vCGPOAcOTmau7tvijj7NPA)

It's been a while since I wrote an answer as complex as this. Takes `(b)(s)(n)`. Explanation coming soon.

Ungolfed:

```scala
b => s => n =>
//Make a range [1,n]
1.to(n) map { y => //Perform these operations on each y
  //Build a list of digits in base b (reversed)
  val toBaseB = Seq.unfold(y) { //Start with y as the quotient
    q =>                        //q is the quotient at each iteration
      //If q is still greater than 0, add another digit
      Option.when(q > 0)(
        q % b,   //The next digit is q mod b
        q / b    //The next quotient is the floor of q÷b
      )
  }
  //Plane and convert back to decimal here
  ((0 +: toBaseB) //First prepend a 0 so that the last digit of toBaseB is counted
    :\ (0, 0, 0) //First accumulator (count 0, prev item 0, sum 0)
  ) {
    //d is the current digit, p is the previous digit,
    //c is the current run length,
    //and a is the sum (partially converted to decimal)
    case (d, (c, p, a)) =>
      if (d == p)     //If the run's still going
        (c + 1, d, a) //Increase the run length
      else            //Otherwise
        (1, d,        //Set the run length to 1 and set p to the new d
          //Add the current run to the sum
          //Make a sequence of (c-s) p's
          //Convert to decimal, and add the previous sum (a) to that
          (a /: Seq.fill(c - s)(p))(_ * b + _)
        )
  }._3 //Only get the sum (planed sequence converted to decimal)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
RbŒgṫ⁵$Ḋ$€F$€ḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8o6eik9Ic7Vz9q3KrycEeXyqOmNW4g4uGO1v///xuZGvw3@W8EAA)

```
RbŒgṫ⁵$Ḋ$€F$€ḅ  Main Link; takes [n, b, s]
R               Range from 1 to n
 b              Base convert (each) into base b
  Œg            Group equal runs (vectorizes)
    (    )-$€   For each number
    ( )-$       - For each run
    ṫ⁵$           - Tail; remove the first s-1 items
       Ḋ          - Dequeue; remove the first element
          F     - Flatten
             ḅ  Convert (each) back from base b
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 11 bytes

```
möB⁰ṁ↓²gB⁰ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fwNqdHjRse7mx81Db50KZ0MGfH4v///xv/N/pvaGgEAA)

```
m           # map the following function 
          ḣ # across all the integers from 1 to arg3
            # the 'plane' function:
 ö          # composition of 4 commands
        B⁰  # get the digits in base arg2
       g    # group equal values
    ṁ↓²     # drop the first arg1 elements from each group, and flatten
  B⁰        # interpret as digits in base arg2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＩＥＥＮ↨⊕ιη↨Φι∧¬‹μθ⬤…⮌…ιμθ⁼νλη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3LCsIwEEX3/YosZyAurMuualEQtIh/ENOBBJK0ebTg18dUEbu4i3vmXEYqEeQoTM4XN82pn@2TAnhsqm1Xpd@Ddgk6ERPcxPTJVkHOjiJSYTKQJZdoAF2gwt/lrE0qouasdQP0Y4IrxQiWM786rTHQvaShTo0TPGihUEZ/UnZ29XzJyc/CRHCcGUT8fkFscj5UdbXf13m3mDc) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes inputs in the order `s`, `b`, `n`. Explanation:

```
ＮθＮη
```

Input `s` and `b`.

```
   Ｎ                        Input `n`
  Ｅ                         Map over implicit range
     ⊕ι                     Current index, 1-indexed
    ↨  η                    Convert to base `b`
 Ｅ                          Map over list
          ι                 Current base conversion
         Φ                  Filtered where
              μ             Current position
            ¬‹ θ            Is not less than `s`
           ∧                Logical And
                 …⮌…ιμθ     Last `s` elements
                ⬤           All satisfy
                        ν   Inner element
                       ⁼    Equal to
                         λ  Outer element
        ↨                 η Convert from base `b`
Ｉ                           Cast to string
                            Implicitly print each result on its own line
```